# Switch between 2 USB connections (1 board with 2 female USB) without mechanical switch

Tags: power-supply, arduino, pcb, pcb-design, switches

I'm trying to create board with an [RP2040](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/hardware-design-with-rp2040.pdf) but there is only micro-USB, so the main idea is to replace it with USB-C and a 4-pin magnetic connector.

I would like to know if there is a way to select only 1 connection out of 2 according to which wire was connected first (or with preference to magnetic pin connection)?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: With the requirement of no analog switch, you are only left with worst possible options and need a mechanical switch. Like a relay. Unfortunately most of them are unsuitable for high speed data such as USB. And magnetic USB connectors violate the specs and many have broken their devices with them, I strongly advice against using magnetic USB connectors. Feel free to change your specs as it isn't really viable to do it without an analog USB switch chip.

Comment: You also appear to have connected both Vbus lines together, which is a complete no-no. You'll need some sort of switching here, or at least disconnect the 5k1 resistors if the USB A is connected.

Comment: Have you Googled usb bus switch IC?

Comment: @Justme , thanks. Especially for pointing out analog chips [I made a mistake with the switch type, this is exactly what I was interested in]

Comment: @Finbarr Thanks, I thought that LDO could withstand power from 2 USB's , so I was looking for a way to separate only the D-D + signals.

In any case, I would like to find a way to isolate the second USB when 1 is already connected.

Comment: It's not about the LDO "withstanding power", it's about connecting two supplies with potentially different voltages together and creating a large current between them.

Comment: The VBUS pins must not be connected together. Imagine powering this from two PCs. Even worse than flowing current from one power supply to another when they are both on; what happens if one computer turns off? Nothing? Will one be powered by the other? Can USB wiring handle amps of current? Will a fuse blow, or the whole set of motherboards and power supplies? There is a reason USB standard says that cables which enable you to connect power supplies or hosts together must not exist.